# Where are official version control repositories for source code of Xenial Xerus packages?

Tags: 16.04, launchpad, version-control, contributing

For Wily Werewolf and previous releases, it was pretty straightforward locating the official source repositories for packages in Launchpad, therefore it was easy to create your own branches and propose merges. For example the repos for Banshee and Deluge were [lp:ubuntu/wily/banshee](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/banshee/wily) and [lp:ubuntu/wily/deluge](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/deluge/wily), respectively. The equivalents for Xenial Xerus, however, are conspicuously no where to be found.

The VCS reported by `apt-get source <package>` now seem to point to upstream Debian sources. For example Banshee's is git://git.debian.org/git/pkg-cli-apps/packages/banshee.git, and indeed this repo does contain a xenial branch, but it doesn't seem to be in sync with the code you get using `apt-get source`. The one for Deluge is a little more promising and seems to be the correct one.

It seems as though Bazaar is now being abandoned for Git, which I would welcome gladly, but what about integration with Launchpad? What is the procedure now for reporting bugs and contributing code?

Answer (score 0):

Use **pull-lp-source** from the **ubuntu-dev-tools** package:

For current development release use

```
pull-lp-source deluge
```

for Xenial release

```
pull-lp-source deluge xenial
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of this tool. However, this is only slightly better than 'apt-get source', since it makes it easier to download a specific version without having to modify your sources.list. It still doesn't give you the benefit of full VCS history.